# Batching Kafka Events using Faust

Tags: apache-kafka, faust

I have a Kafka topic we will call *ingest* that receives an entry every `x` seconds. I have a process that I want to run on this data but it has to be run on 100 events at a time. Thus, I want to batch the entries together and send them to a new topic called *batched-ingest*. The two topics will look like this...

`ingest = [entry, entry, entry, ...]`

`batched-ingest = [[entry_0, entry_1, ..., entry_99]]`

What is the correct way to do this using faust? The solution I have right now is this...

```
app = faust.App("explore", value_serializer="raw")
ingest = app.topic('ingest')
ingest_batch = app.topic('ingest-batch')


@app.agent(ingest, sink=[ingest_batch])
async def test(stream):
    async for values in stream.take(10, within=1000):
        yield values
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this in Faust. If so, what should I set `within` to in order to make it always wait until `len(values) = 100`?

Answer (score 2):

as mentioned in the [faust take documentation](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/streams.html?highlight=take#take-buffer-up-values-in-the-stream) if you omit the `within` from `take(100, within=10)` the code will block forever if there are 99 messages and the last hundredth message is never received. To solve this add a within timeout so that up to 100 values will be processed within 10 seconds. so that if there are periods of 10 seconds with no events received it will still process what it has gathered.

Comment: I can confirm that the above solution works. I've implemented the same thing and it works well for my case where I want 500 events or one second (whichever comes first) using take(500, within=1000). If you must not process until you have exactly 100, then don't set a within parameter. But as @Amedia says, if you get stuck with 99 then it won't process until the 100th comes in. If that might be a problem. then set a generous within time (some buffer) and add some length calc to your stream processor let you know it's only 99 or 98 instead of 100.